# Can this be made tail-recursive in Prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog, stack-overflow, tail-recursion, instantiation-error

I'm learning Prolog, and as an exercise, I'm experimenting with a simple database that calculates the sum of all numbers up to the given number (i.e. 0=0, 1=1, 2=3, 3=6, 4=10, ...). Easy enough:

```
counting_sum(0, 0).
counting_sum(Num, Sum) :- Num > 0, PrevNum is Num - 1,
    counting_sum(PrevNum, PrevSum), Sum is Num + PrevSum.
```

That blows up somewhere around `counting_sum(150000, X).` with a stack overflow. I understand that Prolog can do tail recursion, but if I move the recursive call to the end of the rule, I get

```
error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

which I assume is telling me I can't use `PrevSum` before it's been unified with `counting_sum(PrevNum, PrevSum)`. Is that correct, and is there any way to make this tail-recursive? I'm using GNU Prolog 1.3.1 if that makes any difference.

P.S. I'm still shaky on the terminology. Let me know if I used the terms incorrectly.

Comment: You are right about the cause of the instantiation error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this (use an accumulator):

```
counting_sum(Count, Sum):-
  counting_sum(Count, 0, Sum).

counting_sum(0, Sum, Sum).
counting_sum(Num, PrevSum, Sum):- Num > 0, PrevNum is Num - 1,
    NextSum is PrevSum + Num,
    counting_sum(PrevNum, NextSum, Sum).
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't encountered accumulators. It [looks like a useful idiom](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/prolog/prolog-tutorial.html#iteration). Having read and understood what an accumulator is, I was able to write a new implementation using one and then check it against your code. I came up with the same thing. Problem: I still get a stack overflow at about `counting_sum(350000, X).` Any idea why that is?

Comment: That's strange. I tried the code I provided with SWI with `3500000` (ten times your figure) and it handles it easily.

Comment: I'm speculating, but GNU Prolog may not do tail optimization in interpreted mode (but SWI Prolog does).  @RyanStewart: how about confirming whether you used a compiled gprolog executable, or just the interpreter?

Comment: @hardmath: Yep, good call. After compiling, it works fine. Thanks guys!